# What is the drop order between struct and member?

Tags: rust

If I have:

```rust
struct Bar {}

struct Foo {
  bar: Bar
}

impl Drop for Foo {
  fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

impl Drop for Bar {
  fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
   let x = Foo { bar: Bar {} };
}
```

which drop is called first, the drop for `Foo` or the drop for `Bar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drop for `Foo` will be called before the drop for `Bar`.

If it were the other way around, `&mut self` would refer to partially-destroyed object and `self.bar` would be invalid. This wouldn't make sense with the goals of `Drop` which is too execute logic *before* being destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#:%7E:text=The%20destructor%20of%20a%20type%20T%20consists%20of%3A):

> The destructor of a type `T` consists of:
>
> 1. If `T: Drop`, calling `<T as std::ops::Drop>::drop`
> 2. Recursively running the destructor of all of its fields.

In other words, in your example, when `x` goes out of scope, `Foo::drop` gets called before `Bar::drop` (and any other fields `Foo` may have).

The easiest way to see this, though, is to just [try it out yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87af55fbaab8a453fdcd6111f26c0cf8).